# How to know the source file is write in newline or a line in PHP?

Tags: php

How to know  the source file is write in newline or a line?

I have a file that contains the text:

example:

**file1(can be just only one line) :**

`hello stackoverflow hello stackoverflow hello stackoverflow hello 
stackoverflow hello stackoverflow`

**file2(can be multiple line)**

```
  hello stackoverflow
  hello stackoverflow
  hello stackoverflow
  hello stackoverflow
```

How Can we know that in this file Are there the newline or online with PHP;

UPDATE:

```
<?
$content1 = "lin1 
           lin2";

$content2 = "lin1 lin2";

function file_source_is_new_line($content){
    $data = str_replace(array(chr(13).chr(10),chr(10)),chr(13),$content);
    $matches = count(explode(chr(13),$data));
    echo  count($matches); 
}
file_source_is_new_line($content1);
?>
```

Always give `1` ?

Comment: "We"? You mean community/people? What is the environemnt, that needs to "know" that?

Comment: You're counting it twice... *$matches =* **count** *(explode(chr(13),$data));* and *echo* **count** *($matches);*.    Simply remove the line `echo  count($matches);` and replace `$matches =` with `echo`.

Comment: thanks you Christian Sciberras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents("test.txt");
preg_match('/.*\n.*/', $fileContents, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 1) { /* Yes, we have new-line in string */ }
```

Comment: if you are familiar with regex, then it is easy: preg_match('/.*(\n|\r).*/', $fileContents, $matches);

Comment: I am not .for my case to check the newline .I dont know we have to put "r" or not because .because after I applied your code ,it still not detected the string in file

Comment: Regex to detect two characters? Isn't that way overkill??

Comment: Author didn't ask shortest/{least resource consuming}/{other descriptive factors} that would "tighten belt". So, I am giving first one came in my mind, that does the job. In programming, there are almost neverending ways of solving any problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- Using `file()` function:

  ```
  $lines = count(file('target.php'));
  ```
- Doing it yourself:

  ```
  $data = file_get_contents('target.php');
  $data = str_replace(array(chr(13).chr(10),chr(10)),chr(13),$data);
  $lines = count(explode(chr(13),$data));
  ```

As you may know, line endings are platform dependent; DOS/Win: CRLF, Linux: LF and (old) OSX: CR.

The first method is not cross-platform compatible, while the second one is.

However, the function `file()` has some arguments which might be useful to you:

> > `file( filename [, flags ] )`
> >
> > *filename* - Path to the file.
> >
> > *flags* - The optional parameter flags can be one, or more, of the following constants:
> >
> > - **FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH** - Search for the file in the include_path.
> > - **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** - Do not add newline at the end of each array element
> > - **FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES** - Skip empty lines

Comment: I have used the option1.but it seam not okay

Comment: why not use "\r\n"? what difference?

Comment: Some systems (incorrectly) generate CRLF out of `"\n"` so it ain't right. The chr() approach is more direct. Also, the way I made it resolves CRLF and LF to CR and then counts them as such, making this work on all platforms.

Comment: What are the values you get from method 1? It should work without problems.

Comment: But **WHAT** problem? I can't know what you're doing if you don't say anything about it.

Comment: you can test with $x = "single line"; and $x= "multiple line with new line" a;

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. For one thing, `file()` works on files directly, not strings.